# Is a constant function between topological spaces continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $T\colon X\to Y$ be constant, where $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(Y,\tau_2)$ are topological spaces. Maybe a silly question, but is then $T$ continuous?

It is to show that for $O\in \tau_2$ I have that $T^{-1}(O)\in\tau_1$.

Comment: Yes, a constant function is continuous with respect to the trivial topology on $X$, and therefore with every topology on $X$.

Comment: Then why don't you show (or disprove) it?

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** There are only two cases: either $O$ contains the constant value or it doesn't. What is $T^{-1}(O)$ in the two cases?

Answer (score 1):

This may shed some light, let $1={*}$ be the one point space. There's two key facts about this space:

(1) for every space $X$ there's a unique continuous function $X\rightarrow 1$.

(2) a continuous function $1\rightarrow X$ is just an element $x\in X$.

Then it follows that a constant function $X\rightarrow Y$ between two spaces is the same as an arrow that has a (unique) factorization $X\rightarrow 1\rightarrow Y$. In particular it follows that it's continuous from (1) and (2). There's obviously easier ways to see this but I think this one tell us a little bit more.