# why all constant functions are continuous.$?$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have read that if we let $(X, \tau_x)$ and $(Y, \tau_y)$ be topological spaces, and  $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is constant, then f is continuous. Can anyone please explain why? I assume we must look at the preimage of the open sets in $(Y, \tau_y)$..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080707/is-a-constant-function-between-topological-spaces-continuous)

Answer (score 6):

If $f$ is constant then the preimage of any set is either empty or all of $X$, so it is open. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

When $f(x)=q$ for all $x\in X$,  the inverse image $f^{-1}S$ of ANY $S\subset Y$ is  empty if $q\not \in S$, or is $X$ if $q\in S$,  so $f^{-1}S$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open set in $Y$. Then since $f$ is constant $f^{-1}(U) \in \{ \emptyset,X \}$ and both sets are open in $X$. Hence, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)= a$ constant function. Let $U$ be an open set in $Y$. We will show that $f^{−1}(U)$ is open.

We have  two cases:

$1.a \in U $

$2. a \notin U$.

case $1$ proof : If $a \in U$  ,then $f^{-1}(U)= X$ since $f(x)= a$ for all $ x \in X$. Therefore $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X $

case $2$ proof : If $a \notin  U$ , then $f^{-1}(U)= \emptyset$. we know that $\emptyset$
is always open in any subset

In both case $1$ and $2$ , the preimage of every open set is open .so the  constant function $f$ is continious