# can we say that $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \sqrt{-x^2}=0$ even if the function domain is a singleton $\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In Real analysis, the strict definition of a limit, we take a sequence of point that converging to the point a ["limit point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point). which is not verified here in this case we have only one element in the function domain :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{-x^2}$$

but by replacing $0$ in the function we get $0$

so my question is : in a formal way can we say that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{-x^2}=0$$

Comment: The first thing to try when evaluating limits is to plug the limit point into the expression in the limit. In this case you get $\sqrt{-0^2}=0.$

Comment: I knew that but it doesn't fit the formal definition of a limit

Comment: “Can we say”? I suppose you could, as long as you don’t try to pull any surprise results out of the statement. I think it’s an extension of the definition of very limited utility.

Comment: It's sort of pointless to define limits without neighbourhood of a point, you basically just have $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @kingW3: But there are neighborhoods. The domain $\{0\}$ is a topological space with exactly two open sets: $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$. The latter is an open set containing $0$, so an open neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Vercass One usually looks at neighbourhood without the limit point i.e without $0$ so the only remaining set is the $\emptyset$, you could consider the empty set but I feel it's better to avoid it because the answer is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @kingW3: Depends. The topological definition of continuity considers neighborhoods with the point in question. And the analytical one can also be formulated that way: $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to0,~x\neq x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$, or if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists, where in the second limit, $x$ is allowed to be $x_0$.

Answer (score 3):

We can say so with perfectly good conscience. Ignoring all the notational baggage, the function in question is
$$f:\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb R,~0\mapsto0.$$
Here, $\{0\}$ is a metric space with the only possible metric on a singleton set: $d(0,0)=0$. With this metric, the set $\{0\}$ gains the discrete topology, with respect to which *every* function to *any* other metric space (or even topological space) is continuous. It's not a particularly interesting topology, but it's a perfectly fine one.

Another argument why it's perfectly fine to allow such a function to be continuous: Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a constant map where $X,Y$ are metric spaces (or even topological ones). Then $f$ is continuous. This is a very intuitive statement which is also easy to prove in the context of topology. Your function *is* a constant function between metric spaces, so we'd have to make an exception for this theorem, which in my opinion would be way worse than calling your function continuous.

Comment: there are a lot of contradicting answers, that are based on opinions and i got confused what to accept and with which criteria, and which is the reference in this case.

Comment: @El-Mo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function#Other_properties also says that constant functions between topological spaces (which metric spaces are) are continuous. Though without citation. This question also has answers with the short proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733403/why-all-constant-functions-are-continuous

Comment: Yes, even though the limit of $f$ does not exist, $f$ is continuous. However, that is not what the question is asking.

Comment: @robjohn: it is unnatural to require that $x$ be a limit point. The definition of a limit works perfectly fine without this requirement. Nothing breaks if we don't use it. On the other hand, we get a much stronger connection between continuity and limits if we don't require it, which is good, because the definition of continuity is obviously just a variation of the definition of a limit. I recognize that a broad section of especially undergrad literature does it differently, so I'm not saying you're wrong. Just that we're using our vocabulary differently.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of a limit in a metric space:
$$
\forall\epsilon\gt0,\exists\delta\gt0:0\lt|x-0|\le\delta\implies|f(x)-0|\le\epsilon\tag1
$$
Since there are no $x$ in the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{-x^2}$ that satisfy $0\lt|x-0|\le\delta$, the implication is vacuously true.

---

**However...**

Thanks to Adam Rubinson for pointing out my error. As described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#More_general_subsets), to take the limit of a function at a point $p\in S\subset\mathbb{R}$, it is required that $p\in\overline{S\setminus\{p\}}$. Unfortunately, in this case, $S=\{p\}$, so $p\not\in\overline{S\setminus\{p\}}=\emptyset$. So, although condition $(1)$ is satisfied, we cannot say that
$$\require{cancel}
\cancel{\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{-x^2}=0}\tag2
$$
When $S=\mathbb{R}$, $p\in\overline{S\setminus\{p\}}$ for all $p\in S$, so $(1)$ is sufficient.

Comment: so is it safe to write that $\sqrt{-x²}$ has a limit at $a=0$ ?

Comment: For this definition of a limit, it is vacuously safe. However, as I mention, what that limit is, is not definite.

Comment: Your definition of limit in a metric space is inaccurate. The definition of *limit* in metric space setting, says that, if you are considering whether $0$  is a limit of the function, then $0$ must be a limit point ( of {$0$} ), which is false. In other words, the correct definition of limit of a function in a metric space *does not tell us whether or not* $0$ is a limit point of {$0$}.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Thank you for pointing this out. I have edited my answer.

Comment: When I said,  "does not tell us whether or not $0$ is a limit point of {$0$}", I meant, it does not tell us what $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)\ $ is

Answer (score 0):

In *complex* analysis, the assertion $\lim_{z\to0}\sqrt{-z^2}=0$ is defensibly true even if you don't bother to specify the sign of the square root for nonzero numbers. But as a *real*-valued function of a *real* variable, the expression $\sqrt{-x^2}$ makes no sense except at $x=0$, so it really doesn't make sense to talk about its limit as $x$ tends to $0$. Most formal definitions of limit require the point being tended to to be a "limit point" for the domain of the function, meaning every (punctured) neighborhood of the point has nonempty intersection with the domain. The natural domain for the expression $\sqrt{-x^2}$ as a real-valued function of a real variable is the singleton set $\{0\}$, which has no limit points.

**Added later:** To put things another way, asking for the meaning of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ when $c$ is not a limit point for the domain of $f$ is a little like asking for the meaning of $\gcd(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$.  That is, the greatest common divisor is well defined for pairs of integers (not both $0$), but not for any old pair of numbers; likewise limits are only defined at limit points.  Expressions like $\gcd(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{-x^2}$ can, perhaps, be usefully likened to Noam Chomsky's grammatically correct but semantically nonsensical sentence ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)

Comment: can you name some references cause i get confused between several contradicting answers.

Comment: @El-Mo, the Wikipedia link that Jaap Scherphuis gives beneath Adam Rubinson's answer is one example where the notion of a limit is limited to limit points.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interpret this limit as a complex number. Which can be written as: $$\underset{x\to0}{lim}\hspace{0.3cm}x^2i+0$$
As always, you can separate both parts of the limit to get a more clear view of why the result is a real 0:
$$=\underset{x\to0}{lim}\hspace{0.3cm}x^2i+\underset{x\to0}{lim}\hspace{0.3cm}0 $$
And when you finally evaluate both parts of the limits, you can actually be sure that the real part and the imaginary part are both reaching 0 the closer x is to 0 from left or right (Even if the real part domain is $\{0\}$ since the imaginary part domain is $[0,\infty)$ ).

Comment: you are right but in complex analysis, the very first word i say is that I'm talking about real valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

The function under consideration is $f:x \to \sqrt{-x^2} $ with domain {$0$}. In other words, your function is,  $f:$ {$0$} $\to ${$0$} with $f(0)=0.$ Your question is, "what is $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$?"

Now, let's talk about the domain. $0$ is not a limit point of {$0$} because every neighbourhood of $0$ in {$0$} is {$0$}, so there are *no* neighbourhoods of $0$ that contains a point $q \neq 0$ such that $q \in ${$0$}. Note that this is stronger than we needed: we only needed to show that there exists a neighbourhood of $0$ that does not contain a point $q \neq 0$ such that $q \in ${$0$}.

Now, in order for us to consider the *limit* $\ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ (e.g. going by Rudin's definition), $\ 0$ must be a *limit point* of the domain which we have just seen it is not.

Therefore using the conventional definition of limit of a function at a point in the domain does not tell us anything about $\ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x),\ $ and in fact, I am not sure what the definition or meaning of "$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)\ $" is for the above function, so let's stop talking about things that haven't been defined.

Comment: Most definitions of limit (like the one you link to) explicitly say that $0<|x-p|<\delta$, because the value at the point $x=p$ has no bearing on the value of the limit. In this case it makes the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ game vacuously true for *any* limit value, not just $f(p)$.

Comment: Yes, so it is true because it is vacuously true.

Comment: I think you overlooked the condition (in the Wikipedia link) that the point, in this case $0$, where the limit is being taken be a *limit point* for the domain of the function.